# Node.exe Not Found Under Windows

Tags: windows, node.js

I'm setting up a developer's machine that must run Node.js under Windows 7. However after installing the latest version (0.10.28 as of today), both the x86 and x86_64 flavours, I cannot run it.

The path to the binaries are correctly showing up in my PATH variable (last two paths are added by the Node.js Windows installer) :

```
C:\Users\acastaner>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:
\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Window
sPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program
 Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Manage
ment Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Com
ponents\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\D
AL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Pro
gram Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C
:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;";C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Spirent Communications\Spirent TestCenter 4.40\Layer 4-7
 Application";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Spirent Communications\Spirent TestCenter
4.42\Layer 4-7 Application";C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Users\acastaner\
AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I have confirmed that the C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ directory contains the files npm.cmd and node.exe. However this is what happens:

```
C:\Users\acastaner>npm
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PATH variable has an error: there is an unbalanced quote after `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;`.